# Using integration to derive a volume of the cone using angle $\theta$ with the base

Tags: integration

Let the base of the cone is a circle with radius, $r$, and the height of the cone is $h$, let the vertical line of the cone with length $h$ to have angle $\theta$ with the base. For the cone, angle $\theta = \pi/2$. If we keep $h,r$ fixed, derive formula for the volume of the cone for $\theta \le \pi/2$

to find volume of cone, integrate $\int_a^b A(x) dx$, how do I do this, do I take the area of each triangle ? But how do I integrate it from a to b? why is the volume $\frac{\pi r^2 h \sin \theta}{3}$

Comment: $A(x)$ is the area of the base of a new cone that you would get if you cut the original cone in a plane parallel to the base of the original cone at height x above the original base. Now you integrate these areas with x ranging between 0 and h.

Comment: @HenryT. Wouldn't that just give $\frac{\pi r^2 h}{3}$ which does not prove $\frac{\pi r^2 h \sin \theta}{3}$

Comment: Hm maybe they mean with $h$ the „length of the sloped surface“ and not the height (let‘s call it $\tilde{h}$) of the cone as is it usually understood then: $\tilde{h}=h \sin(\theta)$ and the formula makes sense.